# can't get more functions running in beginner python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm very new to programming. I'm trying to make a simple adventure game but I'm already stuck on trying to get past the first function. Here is my code so far:

```
def find_shelter():
    print "Your crew needs to find shelter for the first night.\n"
    print "Do you choose....\n"
    print "The cave, it is near the water. You will be safe from wind, but there may be animals inside the cave.\n"
    print "The beach, it is very comfortable. You can see boats, but we will be exposed to weather.\n"
    print "The jungle, it has many trees. You will be safe from storms.  However, there are many animals.\n"
    print "The mountain, it is very high.  You will be safe from the jungle animals, but you may fall off the mountain.\n"
    choice = raw_input("Select A for cave, B for beach, C for jungle, or D for mountain. ")
    return choice

def oh_no_cave():
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "There was a flood in the cave, one person drowned and is dead."
    crew = crew - 1
    print "There are now %s people left in your crew.", crew
    return crew

def oh_no_beach():
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "The storm rained on you. One person was struck by lightening and is dead."
    crew = crew - 1
    print "There are now %s people left in your crew.", crew
    return crew

def oh_no_jungle():
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "But, you were safe in the jungle from the storm. Everyone is ok."
    print "There are still %s people left in your crew.", crew

def oh_no_mountain():
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "You all get very wet on the mountain, but everyone is ok."
    print "There are still %s people left in your crew.", crew

choice = []
print "You are going on a cruise with your family and friends.\n"
crew = raw_input("Enter the number of people on the cruise, must be at least four: \n")
print "Oh no! Your crew has just shipwrecked on a desolate island."
print "All food and supplies were lost at sea, and the captain has died too. :( "
print "On the island there is a beach, a river, a jungle, a mountain, and a cave."

if crew != 0:
    find_shelter()
    if choice == "a":
        oh_no_cave()
    elif choice == "b":
        oh_no_beach()
    elif choice == "c":
        oh_no_jungle()
    elif choice == "d":
         oh_no_mountain()
else:
    print "OH NO! Everyone in your crew has died! It's all over...."
    print "Completely over."
```

After the prompt is given for the user to choose a, b, c, d, nothing happens after the user makes a choice. Please let me know what I could do to fix this and any other tips are also welcome. I later plan to check to make sure the user inputted at least 4 crew members but not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: Generally you should post in your question not as a link, also can you reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce your issue

Comment: The error is caused by using codepad; it *doesn't support user input*; I don't think you are asking about that so I omitted it.

Comment: I can guarantee `crew` will never be equal to 0, you always call `find_shelter()` no matter what is entered

Comment: the issues isn't with codepad, if you download it, you can run the code up until you've entered a choice. after you've entered the choice the code is done, it doesn't run the if statement that checks which choice you've entered, that's my main issue. if you could download my code and check it out, i'd be much appreciative, thanks.

Comment: @PistolPete I edited your code and have made some changes, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues with the code provided, I tried to fix some of them.

The problem starts at `if crew != 0:` this is an if statement which would only be ran **once**, depending upon the conditional, As you need to prompt the user multiple times until all the crew members are dead, you must use `while crew != 0:` and Don't forget to change the value of the variable `crew` inside the while loop otherwise it would be an infinite loop.

The other big issue was in line `crew = raw_input("Enter the number of people on the cruise, must be at least four: \n")` which would return a string and hence you won't be able to apply arithmetic operations onto that, So you need to convert that to a `int` by using `crew = int(raw_input("Enter the number of people on the cruise, must be at least four: \n"))`

Now inside the `while` loop you are calling the functions which are indeed changing the value of variable `crew`(which is not a global defined variable) but you are not storing the returned value into any variable.

Also you were missing an `else` clause for handling the issues where the user enters any other input except `"a", "b", "c", "d"`

By fixing all the above issues the final code looks something like:

```
def find_shelter():
    print "Your crew needs to find shelter for the first night.\n"
    print "Do you choose....\n"
    print "The cave, it is near the water. You will be safe from wind, but there may be animals inside the cave.\n"
    print "The beach, it is very comfortable. You can see boats, but we will be exposed to weather.\n"
    print "The jungle, it has many trees. You will be safe from storms.  However, there are many animals.\n"
    print "The mountain, it is very high.  You will be safe from the jungle animals, but you may fall off the mountain.\n"
    choice = raw_input("Select A for cave, B for beach, C for jungle, or D for mountain. ")
    return choice

def oh_no_cave(crew):
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "There was a flood in the cave, one person drowned and is dead."
    crew = crew - 1
    print "There are now %s people left in your crew."% crew
    return crew

def oh_no_beach(crew):
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "The storm rained on you. One person was struck by lightening and is dead."
    crew = crew - 1
    print "There are now %s people left in your crew."% crew
    return crew

def oh_no_jungle(crew):
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "But, you were safe in the jungle from the storm. Everyone is ok."
    print "There are still %s people left in your crew."% crew

def oh_no_mountain(crew):
    print "OH NO! There was a very big storm in the night! It rained and the wind was very strong."
    print "You all get very wet on the mountain, but everyone is ok."
    print "There are still %s people left in your crew."% crew

#choice = []
print "You are going on a cruise with your family and friends.\n"
crew = int(raw_input("Enter the number of people on the cruise, must be at least four: \n"))
print "Oh no! Your crew has just shipwrecked on a desolate island."
print "All food and supplies were lost at sea, and the captain has died too. :( "
print "On the island there is a beach, a river, a jungle, a mountain, and a cave."

while crew != 0:
    choice = find_shelter()
    if choice == "a":
        crew = oh_no_cave(crew)
    elif choice == "b":
        crew = oh_no_beach(crew)
    elif choice == "c":
        crew = oh_no_jungle(crew)
    elif choice == "d":
         crew = oh_no_mountain(crew)
    else:
        print "Please enter a valid choice."
else:
    print "OH NO! Everyone in your crew has died! It's all over...."
    print "Completely over."
```

Comment: thanks anmol_uppal for helping me to clean it up a bit and get to my other if statement. however, I tried using the while but had to go back to using the if statement because it kept looping through find_shelter until the crew was 0, and only then did it run an oh_no function

Comment: nevermind, I think I need to put choice = find_shelter outside the while loop

Comment: Yeah Now it somewhat depends upon you @PistolPete, How you manage the flow of the program. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning the return value of your function to the variable `choice`. You should have done something like this:

```
choice = find_shelter()
```